# Apache Directive for Allow From

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I want to button down write access on a particular file using the **Allow form** directive in my httpd.conf file.

I have a PHP script that I want to be the only resource that can write to this file.

Is there a variation of the Allow from that I can define to make this happen?

Comment: Still interested in knowing if there are useful alternatives on the Allow from other than IP addresses. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to put this file outside of `DocumentRoot` and give it proper privileges. If file is outside `DocumentRoot`, it can be still accessed through php script.

Of course you could use `<Files>` resoruce in Apache config, but for me it is not a proper solution, because file can be still undirectly accessed.

It should look like this:

```
<Files filename.ext>
    Order allow,deny
</Files>
```

Check the [table](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files) in order directive.

Comment: Tried...no success...decided on another route (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230391/php-shell-exec-and-sudo-must-be-setuid-root)